# load url from a text file using python

Tags: python, scrapy, urllib

I put 200 urls in a text file called url.txt like this:

```
url_1
url_2
url_3
....
url_n
```

And i want to go through all of them in python to get the content of each url's page(the text). What is the simplest way go through each url from this text file? scrapy? or just write another script?

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

html =urllib.urlopen('url').read()

soup = BS(html)


print soup.find('div',{'class':'drkgry'})[1].get_text()
```

Comment: What do you need to do exactly? Explaining the purpose might help us help you,

Comment: Your method seems pretty dead simple - can you explain in what way it's not simple enough?

Comment: Also, it looks like each URL is **one** line - why do you say it's **two** lines?

Answer (score 2):

This seems pretty simple - is this what you're looking for?

```
import urllib2

with open('MyFileOfURLs.txt', 'r') as f:
    urls = []
    for url in f:
        urls.append(url.strip())

html = {}
for url in urls:
    urlFile = urllib2.urlopen(url) as urlFile
    html[url] = urlFile.read()
    urlFile.close()

print html
```

Answer (score 1):

Scrapy might be overkill for this task unless you want to crawl really fast (due the async nature), following links, extracting many fields, etc.

A spider for this would be like

```
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider


class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = 'myspider'

    def start_requests(self):
        with open('urls.txt') as fp:
            for line in fp:
                yield Request(line.strip(), callback=self.parse_website)

    def parse_website(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        print hxs.select('//div[@class="drkgry"]/text()').extract()
```

You can skip creating a full project. Save it as `myspider.py` and run `scrapy runspider myspider.py` having the `urls.txt` file in the same directory.